# Visual Studio 2010 - Solution not under Mercurial version control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, visualhg

I have Visual Studio Ultimate edition, and have installed TortoiseHg and VisualHg.

I'm a total n00b to version control, and had previously added my solution under version control somehow (don't exactly remember how.. think I did that by right clicking inside the solution folder and using tortoisehg context menu)..

Now, whenever I try to commit or check status using visualhg in vs2010, i'm getting "Solution is not under Mercurial Version Control".

I searched stackoverflow, and followed the answer given for this question: [How to use Mercurial from Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286531/how-to-use-mercurial-from-visual-studio-2010), but hg init tells me that the repository already exists.

Please help me out to automatically take a backup of my work everytime I quit Visual studio. If there is a better tool (must be n00b friendly) out there than Mercurial, please suggest that too. Thanks!

Thanks!

**Update**

Looks like I had two solutions with the same name in different directories. I had added the wrong directory under mercurial and tried unsuccessfully to manage a different solution using Visualhg.

Solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had two solutions with the same name in different directories. I had added the wrong directory under mercurial and tried unsuccessfully to manage a different solution using Visualhg.

Solved now.